# Select-Object CmdLet fails when used inside a FunctionDefinition of New-PSSessionConfigurationFile

Tags: powershell

Consider this example below, where I am creating a constrained management end-point. My objective is to create a "proxy" function over the Get-EventLog CmdLet. This example, works as expected until I add *| Select-Object -First 5*. When I do this I get the following error message: "*A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'First'*". Why?

```
$getAppEventLog = {
    #this throws an error, see below
    get-eventlog -log application | Select-Object -First 5 

    #this works
    #get-eventlog -log application    
}

New-PSSessionConfigurationFile -Path c:\PSScripts\panos.pssc `
                               -Description 'Delegation EndPoint Repro' `
                               -ExecutionPolicy Restricted `
                               -SessionType RestrictedRemoteServer `
                               -LanguageMode FullLanguage `
                               -FunctionDefinitions @{Name="Get-AppEventLog";ScriptBlock=$getAppEventLog; Options="AllScope"}

Unregister-pssessionconfiguration -name EventLogManagement -force
Test-PSSessionConfigurationFile -Path c:\PSScripts\panos.pssc
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Path 'c:\PSScripts\panos.pssc' `
                                -Name EventLogManagement `
                                -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI `
                                -AccessMode Remote `
                                -Force

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName localhost -ConfigurationName EventLogManagement
Get-AppEventLog
Select-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'First'.
At line:2 char:51
+     get-eventlog -log application | Select-Object -First 5
+                                                   ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Select-Object
```

PowerShell Info

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                        
PSVersion                      4.0                                                                                                                                                                                          
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                          
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                                                                      
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209                                                                                                                                                                              
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400                                                                                                                                                                               
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                                                                                                                                                                         
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

After thinking about this, I realized the issue could be reproduced in a simpler way - without the function definition. 
When SessionType is equal to RestrictedServer, the following two Cmdlets are available: Get-Command and Select-Object. Therefore, I could reproduce my issue by simply executing something like this:

```
[localhost]: PS> Get-Command | Select-Object -first 1
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'first'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Select-Object
```

Given that, I can create a session that reproduces the issue, like so:

```
New-PSSessionConfigurationFile -Path c:\PSScripts\panos.pssc `
                               -Description 'Delegation EndPoint Repro' `
                               -ExecutionPolicy Restricted `
                               -SessionType RestrictedRemoteServer `
                               -LanguageMode FullLanguage


Unregister-pssessionconfiguration -name EventLogManagement -force
Test-PSSessionConfigurationFile -Path c:\PSScripts\panos.pssc
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Path 'c:\PSScripts\panos.pssc' `
                                -Name EventLogManagement `
                                -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI `
                                -AccessMode Remote `
                                -Force
```

**Hence, I can rephrase my original question as: Why does Select-Object Cmdlet does not work in a restricted session, given the above registration parameters.**

Comment: this works for me. Which powershell version are you using?

Comment: Edit my question by providing $PSVersionTable output

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue, creating a PS endpoint as a wrapper around the PSPKI module. The PSPKI module uses the Select-Object as well, giving the same error.

The solution for me was to update my endpoint .psrc file to include an AliasDefinition for Select-Object to point to the FQDN Select-Object.

AliasDefinitions = @{ Name = 'Select-Object' ; Value = 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Select-Object' }

See also: https://jamesone111.wordpress.com/2016/07/01/just-enough-admin-and-constrained-endpoints-part-2-startup-scripts/

Grtx, 
BvZanten

Answer (score 0):

Instead can you please try to use:

```
Get-EventLog -log application -newest 5
```

Comment: MysticHeroes, thanks for your suggestion, but I do need to get Select-Object to work. Actually, my real scenario is much more complex and is using different set of CmdLets. I used the Get-EventLog example to create the simplest re-pro I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

With a SessionType *RestrictedRemoteServer* the function *Select-Object* is not the same as in a Default-SessionType:

> [RestrictedRemoteServer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849712.aspx). Includes only the following **proxy functions**: Exit-PSSession, Get-Command, Get-FormatData, Get-Help, Measure-Object, Out-Default, and Select-Object. Use the parameters of this cmdlet to add modules, functions, scripts, and other features to the session.

That issue is described here with some workarounds: [Constrained PowerShell endpoints – Visible cmdlets, session types, and language modes](https://4sysops.com/archives/constrained-powershell-endpoints-visible-cmdlets-session-types-and-language-modes/):

> A proxy function is a wrapper function around the original cmdlet that modifies the capabilities of the cmdlet, for example, by adding or **removing parameters**.